# React API data and Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-state

I am new to React. Trying to build random project.
I create one home page where I fetched data from API and set it to some state X.
Using `react-router`, routed to `Category` page where all categories are present.
Again, routed to particular category.
Here all items are visible of that category.
Till here, everything works fine, but when I am refreshing page on this `Items` page, suddenly, all data is vanished.
Any idea what could be wrong?

[image: Component tree]

App

```
useEffect(function () {
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/gahlot1999/fake-api/categories`);
      const data = await res.json();
      setData(data);
    } catch {
      alert('Error in loading data');
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }
  fetchData();
}, []);

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route
      path='/app'
      element={<AppLayout data={data} isLoading={isLoading} />}
    />
    <Route
      path='app/:name'
      element={<Category data={data} isLoading={isLoading} />}
    />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Category

```
function Category({ data, isLoading }) {
  const { name } = useParams();
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <SideBar name={name} />
      <ItemList name={name} data={data} isLoading={isLoading} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

ItemList

```
function ItemList({ name, data }) {
  const items = data.filter(
    (el) => name.toLowerCase() === el.name.toLowerCase(),
  )[0].items;

  return (
    <ul className={styles.itemList}>
      {items.map((el) => (
        <Item item={el} key={crypto.randomUUID()} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Item

```
function Item({ item }) {
  return (
    <li>
      <p>{item.name}</p>
      <p>{item.description}</p>
      <p>{item.price}</p>
    </li>
  );
}
```

AppLayout

```
function AppLayout({ data, isLoading }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.app}>
      <Header />
      <CategoryList data={data} isLoading={isLoading} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Category List

```
function CategoryList({ data, isLoading }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.categoryList}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {data.map((el) => (
            <CategoryItem data={el} key={el.id} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Category Item

```
function CategoryItem({ data }) {
  const { name, description, avatar } = data;
  return (
    <li>
      <Link className={styles.categoryItem} to={`${name.toLowerCase()}`}>
        <img src={avatar} alt='Category Image' />
        <div>
          <h3>{name}</h3>
          <p>{description}</p>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: "Suddenly, all data is vanished. Any idea what could be wrong?" - Was the fetched data stored in state X persisted/initialized so it's still available after a page reload? We can't address issues in code we can't see to please do [edit] the post to include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are referring to.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, Added code snippets. Could you please suggest.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the `Category` component's complete code? I suspect the issue is with the `name` prop that is passed to `ItemList` from `Category`, but we can't see what `name` is.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, edited. Also added AppLayout code, where even after refreshing, data is not getting lost.

Comment: Thanks. I see, it is the route path parameter. Well, if `data` is available in `AppLayout` when you reload the page, it should also be available for `Category` and `ItemList`. I don't see a way for it to only work in one and not the other. Can you create a running codesandbox demo?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese,
Link - codesandbox.io/s/gallant-flower-zycy5x?file=/src/App.jsx
Step to reproduce - After clicking on Click Me button. Refresh categories page and see, its working. Then select any category and after that refresh the page. Then you can see, its not working. In both components, data is passed from App component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254607/discussion-between-ashish-gahlot-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `ItemList` component is incorrectly assuming the `data` array passed to it is populated.

```js
const items = data.filter(
  (el) => name.toLowerCase() === el.name.toLowerCase(),
)[0].items;
```

Remember that `Array.prototype.filter` potentially returns an empty array if (a) it is already an empty array or (b) no element in the array satisfies the predicate function. The issue above comes when the app is on the sub-route and the page reloads and the `data` has yet to be fetched and stored into state. `data.filter(...)` returns an empty array, so there is no zeroth element to access an `items` property of.

## Solution

Guard against potential undefined accesses and provide a fallback `items` value that is still an array so the `items.map(el => ....)` in the component code functions correctly.

```js
const items =
  (data || []).filter((el) => name.toLowerCase() === el.name.toLowerCase())[0]
    ?.items || [];
```

Additionally, you could help your app a bit by not blowing the data away only to refetch it when the page is simply reloaded.

The `data` state could be persisted to and initialized from localStorage. When the page is loaded/reloaded, the last state that was persisted is provided as the initial state value. When the state updates a `useEffect` hook persists the state to localStorage.

Example:

```js
const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => {
  // lazy initialize state from localStorage
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
});

// Persist state updates to localStorage.
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
}, [data]);

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/gahlot1999/fake-api/categories`);
      const data = await res.json();
      setData(data);
    } catch {
      alert('Error in loading data');
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  if (!data) {
    fetchData();
  }
}, [data]);

...
```

### Demo forked from your sandbox

[image: Edit react-api-data-and-routing]

To test, follow your reproduction steps, then additionally do:

1. Reload the page and note that `fetchData` ***is not*** called and the UI is stable since the state was peristed.
2. Go into the browser dev-tools and clear the localStorage and reload the page. Note that `fetchData` ***is*** called, and once the data is fetched and set into state the item details correctly render.

Comment: In AppLayout component, I am using same state and on refresh also, it is loading data normally.
`function AppLayout({ data, isLoading }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.app}>
      <Header />
      <CategoryList data={data} isLoading={isLoading} />
    </div>
  );
}`
`function CategoryList({ data, isLoading }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.categoryList}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {data.map((el) => (
            <CategoryItem data={el} key={el.id} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}`

Comment: @AshishGahlot Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you clarify? `AppLayout`'s data is the `data` state that is/was persisted in the `App` component.

Comment: No, State is present in App not in AppLayout. and in AppLayout, on page reload, Data is not getting lost. How come, it is working this way for different components.

Comment: @AshishGahlot Hmm, if `data` is available in `App` and passed to one component, it should be available for any component. I feel I may have misunderstood something. Perhaps there's an issue with the passed `name` prop to `Items`? Can you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Comment: @AshishGahlot Sorry, had to sleep at some point. I see your sandbox and have updated my answer to help address the other issues. FWIW when I applied *just* my initial suggestion against your sandbox, the items details page worked without issue, but there were obvious logical issues and edge cases regarding the `data` array and filtering that also needed to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the issue is in ItemList component. when I am refreshing the page I am getting below error -
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')*

the issue here is in this piece of code -

```
const items = data.filter(
    (el) => name.toLowerCase() === el.name.toLowerCase(),
  )[0].items;
```

we are accessing the 0 index of the filtered data without checking if it ever exists or not. as the api calls are asynchronous, before the data loads from api call, the data prop is empty here. so we are trying to access [0] index of empty array hence the error and page is not loading.

quick workaround, update the component like below -

```
function ItemList({ name, data }) {
  if (!data.length) return <></>
  const items = data.filter(
    (el) => name.toLowerCase() === el.name.toLowerCase(),
  )[0].items;
  return (
    <ul className={styles.itemList}>
      {items.map((el, i) => (
        <Item item={el} key={i} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

or you can provide checks in other ways whichever suits you. maybe render this component when we have length for data. hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Hi
ItemList is coming from Category component. In Category component, I am already checking, if isLoading state is true or false which has been set is API call. But why it is not considering this. Could you please check and advise.
`{isLoading ? (
        <p>Hello</p>
      ) : (
        <>
          <SideBar name={name} />
          <ItemList name={name} data={data} isLoading={isLoading} />
        </>
      )}`

Comment: @AshishGahlot, it is because you are conditioning it based on isLoading. setIsLoading and setData is asynchronously happening. so even if isLoading is false, it doesn't mean data have the desired values.  if you add another condition like below, it will solve the issue. 
{!!data.length && <ItemList name={name} data={data} isLoading={isLoading} />}
in Category component.

Comment: Hi, Understood. Got confused because same code is working for CategoryList but its not working for Category component. Could you please check. Why is it behaving differently.

Comment: It's not same code actually. if you look closely you are looping though the data directly in CategoryList which is passed as props but in Category->ItemList you are filtering it first and then looping through this data - filteredArray[0].items.
you can see you are trying to access an index directly here which is causing the issue. but in CategoryList component you are not trying to do such. that's why it is working fine. 
Let me know if this clears up your queries. and please upvote my answer if you find it useful. :)

Comment: Understood. Definitly found useful and upvoted. :)
Just to conclude, for API data from parent component. We can directly map over it but if we are doing any filter or checking any particular value then we have to check if data exist or not. Why we don't have to check in case of map...why it is not throwing error in that case.
Whats the reason, map works fine but check particular thing doesn't.

Comment: just to clarify, map works fine cause you can map an empty array []. or use can use any utility functions ex.map, filter, reduce, find etc on empty array. but you can not access the elements of an empty array cause it's already empty. by doing that we were forcing the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is related to the data fetching and how you handle the initial state in your application.

When you refresh the page on the "Items" page, the data fetched on the home page is lost because the component tree is re-rendered from the top. This means the data state in your App component becomes empty, causing an error when rendering the Category component.

To resolve this, you need to make sure that the data fetched in the Home component is available even after refreshing the page. One common approach is to use browser local storage or session storage to persist the fetched data across page refreshes.

Here's a modified version of your code to handle data fetching and persistence using local storage:

In the App component, check if the data exists in local storage and use it as the initial state. If not, fetch the data and save it in local storage.

```
// App component
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(() => {
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem('data');
    return storedData ? JSON.parse(storedData) : [];
  });
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/gahlot1999/fake-api/categories`);
        const data = await res.json();
        setData(data);
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data)); // Save data to local storage
      } catch {
        alert('Error in loading data');
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      {/* Routes and other components */}
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

By using useState with a function as the initial state, you ensure that the data is fetched only on the first load or when the local storage is empty.

With this modification, when you refresh the "Items" page or navigate back to it, the data should be available from the local storage, preventing the data loss issue you were facing.

Comment: Hi @crystalthinker, understood it.
Can you please explain why I am not facing this issue in AppLayout component. On refresh, data is getting fetched automatically.

Comment: Added code also for AppLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be sure without seeing the rest of you code,

but could it be that when you route to the `Category` page you have the data in state, and it can `.filter` / `.map` through the array of items.

Once you refresh on that page the data is not available at first and the app crashes on the array methods. Assuming that data is `null` or `undefined` at first.

Edit: The issue was in the filter, it seems like your filter function is meant to find one item out of the list I would suggest using the `.find` array method

Final edit: Took a look again, now mapping correctly through the category items

So a rewrite of the ListItem component gives us:

```js
import styles from "./ItemList.module.css";

import Item from "./Item";

function ItemList({ name, data }) {
  const category = data.find(
    (el) => name.toLowerCase() === el.name.toLowerCase()
  );

  if (!category) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <ul className={styles.itemList}>
      {category.items.map((item) => (
        <Item item={item} key={crypto.randomUUID()} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default ItemList;
```

Here is the forked code sandbox: [codesandbox.io/s/clever-shannon-fnp5yq](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-shannon-fnp5yq?file=/src/Components/ItemList.js)

Comment: After you updated, I see you have a loader in AppLayout/CategoryList, not in Categore/ItemList. The loader is what catches your app from crashing, I suspect adding a loader to Category would give the same result when refreshing.
if(isLoading) return <Spinner />;
In Category should do it

Comment: Tried it, stil it is not working. It looks, when I am refreshing on ItemList, data is not being fetched at all. Because isLoading completed is False throughout the process.

Comment: Forked it and got it working https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-shannon-fnp5yq
Removed `[0].items` in src/Components/ItemList line 9